# How can i make a txt file automatically download to computer in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, windows, html

I built an HTML page that uses the HTML5 function [navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition).

The JavaScript writes the longitude, latitude and accuracy to the screen,
but I'm looking for a way to to put that data into a text file and download it automatically to a specific directory in my computer (Windows7) for a Python program to read it later.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function showLocation(position) {
       var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
       var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
       var accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;
       document.write("LAT:" + latitude + "_LON:" + longitude+ "_ACU:" + accuracy);

    }

    function errorHandler(err) 
    {
        var x
        switch(error.code) 
        {
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                x = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
                break;
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                x = "Location information is unavailable."
                break;
            case error.TIMEOUT:
                x = "The request to get user location timed out."
                break;
            case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                x = "An unknown error occurred."
                break;
        }
        document.write(x)
    }   
     function getLocation(){
        if(navigator.geolocation){
           // timeout at 60000 milliseconds (60 seconds)
           var options = {timeout:60000,enableHighAccuracy:true};
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation, errorHandler, options);
        }

        else{
           alert("Sorry, browser does not support geolocation!");
        }
     }

  </script>
```

Comment: what do you mean? @inquisitiveIdiot

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot OP isn't downloading files from the internet. He's trying to save data generated by the javascript.

Comment: @tdelaney Ah I see now. Retract previous objection. Does my answer cover the problem with what he is trying to do?

Comment: To be clear. You want the file to be saved on the computer running the browser not the server? Assuming they are different machines

Comment: yes, file will be saved on client computer running the browser

Answer (score 0):

You need to make either the submit a form or perform an ajax call. This cannot be done in pure javascript on the client side to my knowledge. If you like python then you can use a python web framework like [these](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks/)

The main problem here is the difference between client and server. You don't really want people to be able to write files to your computer from the website you are hosting.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll look into it